# Move SQL columns to new entries in a new table

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, sql-update

This is something I would do very easy in a C# program, but in SQL, well, I don't know if you can.

I have a table Formats. This table have "filename" and a "size". I want to move these into a new table, DigitalFormat, with a foreign key.

So far I've done the easy part:

```
CREATE TABLE FormatDigital
(
FormatDigitalId uniqueidentifier NOT NULL,
Filename nvarchar(MAX) NOT NULL,
Size int NOT NULL
PRIMARY KEY (FormatDigitalId)
);

ALTER TABLE Formats
ADD FormatDigital uniqueidentifier
GO

ALTER TABLE Formats
ADD CONSTRAINT FK_FormatDigital_FormatDigital FOREIGN KEY (FormatDigital)
REFERENCES FormatDigital(FormatDigitalId);
```

I now want to take all the records in Formats, create new entries in FormatDigital, and make sure that the Format.FormatDigitalId foreign key points at the correct ID.

Is this something you can do in SQL? Or should I just hook up a C# program and be awesome?

Comment: Are filename and size unique to each row in Format?

Comment: Is there a reason that you're adding an entirely new table but just copying data over instead of just adding a new column to Formats to indicate that the format is digital?

Comment: I assumed that Filename and size aren't unique? Maybe that's not the case, good question, Jason.

Comment: Does `Formats` have a unique identifier?

Comment: Kyle: No, it's just some random data (just text). 
Jason: Yes, we are going to have some other tables than the digital ones, with a lot of other information (basically going to be a mess otherwise)
Lomak: Thanks
PinnyM: Yes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just do something like

```
INSERT INTO FormatDigital
Select Filename, Size from Format
```

And then

```
UPDATE F
SET
FormatDigital = FD.FormatDigitalID
FROM
Format F
Inner Join
FormatDigital FD
on FD.FileName = F.FileName and FD.Size = F.Size
```

If your filenames and sizes aren't unique, add a DISTINCT to the first query.

Comment: DISTINCT will add a single record in FormatDigital for multiple Format rows.

Comment: And if two Format records share the same filename and size, they should point to the same FormatDigitalID. Otherwise what's the point of having a child table?

Comment: That depends on the purpose of the second table, which hasn't yet been explained...

Comment: The purpose of the table is just to have additional information in a one-to-one relationship

Answer (score 1):

After creating the FormatDigital table, as you have, (except use a Integer Primary Key, set to be an Identity)

```
   CREATE TABLE FormatDigital
    ( FormatDigitalId integer Identity Primary Key NOT NULL,
      Filename nvarchar(MAX) NOT NULL,
      Size int NOT NULL);


   Insert FormatDigital(FileName, Size)
   Select distinct FileName, Size From Formats
   -- ----------------------------------------
   Update F Set FormatDigital =
        D.FormatDigitalId 
   From Format F Join FormatDigital D 
      On  D.Filename = F.Filename
         And D.Size = F.Size
```

If you really want to use a Guid for a key, (Lots of downsides to this.)
Add those later, and then remove the integer keys

Comment: This is essentially the same answer as @KyleHale, with the same problem - it's not guaranteed to be one-to-one

Comment: Yes it is, that's what the Distinct does.

Comment: If 2 Format records exist with the same filename and size, only 1 (shared) FormatDigital record will be created.  That is many-to-one, not one-to-one.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, change your `FormatDigitalId` to use a sequential GUID by default:

```
FormatDigitalId uniqueidentifier NOT NULL DEFAULT newsequentialid()
```

Now you can use the following cursor.  Note that this code assumes that `Formats` has an integer primary key named `Id` - if this is not the case change `@nextId` to the proper type and change `Id` to the correct name:

```
DECLARE @nextId int
DECLARE @filename nvarchar(max)
DECLARE @size int
DECLARE @newId guid

DECLARE loop CURSOR FOR
SELECT Id, Filename, Size
FROM Formats

OPEN loop
FETCH NEXT FROM loop INTO @nextId, @filename, @size

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN

    INSERT INTO FormatsDigital (Filename, Size) 
            OUTPUT inserted.FormatDigitalID INTO @newId 
            VALUES (@filename, @size)

    UPDATE Formats SET FormatDigitalId = @newID WHERE Id = @nextId

    FETCH NEXT FROM loop INTO @nextId, @filename, @size
END

CLOSE loop
DEALLOCATE loop
```